# Align button in span

Tags: html, css

I am trying to align a button placed inside span, it looks fine in desktop browser but in mobile browser the button is not aligned centred, see attached image

[image]

I have simple css attached to the span

```
.navigatebutton
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border-radius:50px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

and the html look like below

**For RIGHT navigation button**

```
<span style='top: calc(45% - 10px); right:2%; position:absolute;' class='navigatebutton preview-next'><button aria-hidden='true' data-icon='\e62d;' class='icon-arrow-right2' style='margin-top: 7px; background: rgba(0,0,0,0);'></button></span>
```

**For LEFT navigation button**

```
<span style='position:relative;top: calc(45% - 10px); left: 2%; class='navigatebutton preview-previous'><button aria-hidden='true' data-icon='\e630;' class='icon-arrow-left2' style='margin-top: 7px; background: rgba(0,0,0,0);' ></button></span>
```

**I am using icommon font for the arrows**.

Please help to align the arrows perfectly.

Cheers.

Comment: I'm not sure if you've supplied sufficient code for us to narrow down the issue. Could you create a [mcve] for us? Just the HTML and CSS for the button with the arrow in it would probably be sufficient, provided it reproduces the problem.

Comment: On the button try: `margin: 0 auto;`  https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Comment: @iphonic.. Try adding top:50% and left:50% to your css classes icon-arrow-left2 and icon-arrow-right2 and remove margin-top from button style.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but none of the above works.

Comment: @Serlite The code above is exactly like this, there is nothing extra in it.

Comment: Does this occur in different mobile browsers (if you have access to multiple)?

Comment: @Serlite Yes it occurs to mobile device, though I figured out the problem, thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your help.

I figured out the solution, culprit was `border-radius`which supposed to be **half the width** to make circle, the value was greater and thus it was failing. So the correct `css` would be

```
.navigatebutton
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:40px;
    height:40px;
    border-radius:20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    font-size:20px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    text-decoration:none;
    cursor: pointer;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,.3);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: If you know that you want your border-radius to always be half of your width/height, consider using percentages: `border-radius: 50%;` Also the `border-radius` element [is supported by all current browsers](http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius) so there's no need for your Webkit and Mozilla vendor prefixes.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for you https://jsfiddle.net/ezj1Lfbw/11/

change `.navigatebutton{display: flex}`

change `margin-top: 7px;` to `margin: auto`

Comment: I tried this but it didn't work.. may be something to do with the icon class

Comment: I have found that changing width, height and border-radius changes the position of the arrow, any idea?